# C# SharePoint CSOM: Update multiline text field

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I wrote a little C# app to retrieve data from several SP custom lists. This has been going very smoothly for months. Now I updated my app to alter some items. To be exact I like to update one multiline text field for some items. Here is my code:

```
// Update SharePoint list elements
foreach (var o in toWrite) // List<(int, string)>();
{
    List destList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listToUpdate); // listToUpdate: SP list name
    ListItem listItem = destList.GetItemById(o.Item1); // o.Item1: id to update

    listItem[fieldToUpdate] = o.Item2.ToString(); // o.Item2: new string for plain text multiline field
    listItem.Update();

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The `ExecuteQuery()` fails with an error "Invalid request."

Writing a single line text field with max. 255 chars this method works fine, so I assume that for multiline text fields I need to somehow handle this long strings in another way. Unfortunately I couldn't find any suitable FieldValue classes in the API.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jerry_MSFTs code as well as mine work fine. The issue with SharePoint Online is that requests will fail when the custom field you like to update is named "Properties". After creating a field with another name everything works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

What's the detailed characters for updating the multiple line text field ?

I tested the code snippet, it's working to update the field:

```
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/MyDev");
        Web web = ctx.Web;
        ctx.Load(web);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList");
        ListItem item = list.GetItemById(1);
        item["Note"] = "TestCharacter";
        item.Update();
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

[image]